# Customize Apache error message "You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port."

Tags: apache, https, port, customization, message

I have an Apache running at port 8080. Recently only http, but now only https. Is there a way to edit (customize) the error message that Apache sends when I accidentally access http://www.example.com:8080 instead of the https:// version?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
<blockquote>Hint: <a href="https://www.example.com:8080/"><b>https://www.example.com:8080/</b></a></blockquote></p>
</body></html>
```

Well, then I could create an automatic redirection...

Any acceptable solution must work with only one port (8080)!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Using ErrorDocument only changes 400 into 302 and replaces the error message with the link to the error document... so it does not actually use the error document for the message.
Edit: Maybe this is a browser limitation...